# QTextStream вывести строку дважды

Tags: c++, qt

Считываю файл:

```
if (V_on(stream1.readLine(),stream2.readLine()))
{
  stream << (stream1.readLine() + "\n");
}
```

и мне нужно считать эту строку снова после выполнения условия, не перенося указатель на следующую строку и не создавая буферных переменных.
Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: На самом деле временный QString у вас по любому создается (readLine же его возвращает) и передается в V_on как аргумент. Так может, его и использовать? Например, перенести вывод в stream в саму функцию V_on?

Comment: Ну или завести явно временный буфер и не изгаляться? Или это дурацкое учебное задание?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать буферную переменную.

Comment: Вы же сами написали в вопросе: *«... не создавая буферных переменных»*. И тут же нарушаете своё требование.